Keycloak validate token
I have only one realm in keycloak with two clients.
Users can belong to one of the two, or even both applications.
My question is: Is there a way to validate tokens without introspecting the token and analyzing the "groups" to which the token owner belongs?
That is, in a hypothetical scenario:
If a user only has access to application 1, when he tries to access application 2 with the token received by application 1, he should receive an "access not permitted", a 401 or something similar.
Is there a method or something defined for this (without looking at the groups within the token)?
Last question:
Am I breaking rules by having two applications in the same realm like this?
Or would it be right to have two different applications in different realms?
For now I've been doing this by looking inside the tokens in the role/group "tabs", but it doesn't seem like it's the best way to do what I need (a little insecure, I don't know)
